# Structure Issue: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Length 20

    struct Capacitor
    {
        char Model[Length];
        int Capacitance;
        float Voltage;
        float Cost;
    };

void displayCapacitorInfo(struct Capacitor List[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Capacitor %s:\n\n", List[i].Model);
        printf("   *Capacitance: %d uF\n", List[i].Capacitance);
        printf("   *Voltage: %f V\n", List[i].Voltage);
        printf("   *Cost: $%f\n", List[i].Cost);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    float Cost, Voltage;
    int Capacitance;
    char Model[Length];

    struct Capacitor a;
    struct Capacitor b;
    struct Capacitor c;
    struct Capacitor d;

    strcpy(a.Model, "11-123U");
    a.Capacitance = 100;
    a.Voltage = 25;
    a.Cost = 6.00;

    strcpy(b.Model, "65T91a");
    b.Capacitance = 22000;
    b.Voltage = 20;
    b.Cost = 25.00;

    printf("Model number of 1st capacitor: %s\n", a.Model);
    printf("Voltage of 2nd capacitor: %f V\n", b.Voltage);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Model number of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%s", &c.Model);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Capacitance of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%d", &c.Capacitance);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Voltage of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &c.Voltage);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Cost of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &c.Cost);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Model number of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%s", &d.Model);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Capacitance of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%d", &d.Capacitance);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Voltage of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &d.Voltage);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Cost of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &d.Cost);
    printf("\n\n");

    struct Capacitor List[] = { {a.Model, a.Capacitance, a.Voltage, a.Cost}, {b.Model, b.Capacitance, b.Voltage, b.Cost}, {c.Model, c.Capacitance, c.Voltage, c.Cost}, {d.Model, d.Capacitance, d.Voltage, d.Cost} };

    displayCapacitorInfo(List);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN1ch.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTceY.png)

I am having trouble with my array List[], specifically when I try to input the model number of my capacitors. The Model element of structures a, b, c, and d produces a "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast" warning when entered into the array List[].

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change to: `struct Capacitor List[] = {a, b, c, d};`

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thank you, this worked.

Comment: Please copy and paste the warnings (and result) as text for us, so that the search engine doesn't have to parse your image file to index this question for future generations. Please remember this for the rest of your life, because people putting text into images (like you) are contributing quickly to the death of the internet.

Comment: ^You're a jack ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First when using scanf("%s") into struct you shouldn't use &. Check how to use scanf properly with strings.

Then the line with `struct Capacitor List[]` I don't know what you want to do with it but isn't it easier just to create array of pointers on those already created structures like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Length 20

struct Capacitor
{
    char Model[Length];
    int Capacitance;
    float Voltage;
    float Cost;
};

void displayCapacitorInfo(struct Capacitor List[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Capacitor %s:\n\n", List[i].Model);
        printf("   *Capacitance: %d uF\n", List[i].Capacitance);
        printf("   *Voltage: %f V\n", List[i].Voltage);
        printf("   *Cost: $%f\n", List[i].Cost);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    float Cost, Voltage;
    int Capacitance;
    char Model[Length];

    struct Capacitor a;
    struct Capacitor b;
    struct Capacitor c;
    struct Capacitor d;

    strcpy(a.Model, "11-123U");
    a.Capacitance = 100;
    a.Voltage = 25;
    a.Cost = 6.00;

    strcpy(b.Model, "65T91a");
    b.Capacitance = 22000;
    b.Voltage = 20;
    b.Cost = 25.00;

    printf("Model number of 1st capacitor: %s\n", a.Model);
    printf("Voltage of 2nd capacitor: %f V\n", b.Voltage);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Model number of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%s", c.Model);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Capacitance of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%d", &c.Capacitance);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Voltage of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &c.Voltage);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Cost of 3rd capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &c.Cost);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Model number of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%s", d.Model);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Capacitance of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%d", &d.Capacitance);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Voltage of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &d.Voltage);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Cost of 4th capacitor:");
    scanf("%f", &d.Cost);
    printf("\n\n");

    //struct Capacitor List[] = { {a->Model, a.Capacitance, a.Voltage, a.Cost}, {*b.Model, b.Capacitance, b.Voltage, b.Cost}, {*c.Model, c.Capacitance, c.Voltage, c.Cost}, {*d.Model, d.Capacitance, d.Voltage, d.Cost} };
    struct Capacitor *List;
    List = malloc(4*sizeof(struct Capacitor*));
    List[0] = a;
    List[1] = b;
    List[2] = c;
    List[3] = d;
    displayCapacitorInfo(List);

    return 0;

}
```

This is just a quick example, it should be more dynamic than actually using `List[0] = a;` etc.